# How do you handle such routing errors in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I occasionally see such errors in the log file, how do I handle this.

```
Started GET "/w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.Win32:)" for 69.25.37.166 at 2013-01-02 00:06:05 +0000

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/w00tw00t.at.ISC.SANS.Win32:)"):
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

**routes.rb**

```
match '*a', :to => 'errors#routingIssue'
```

**create error controller - errors_controller.rb**

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def routingIssue
    render_404
  end
end
```

Comment: yea, it means match '/something' => 'pages#something'

Comment: Is it a wildcard for any other URL, should this be at the end of the routes file.

Comment: Please visit this link for more clarification .. http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/36-rails-3-0-rescue-from-routing-error-solution